# iOS/Swift: "No such module..." for UI Testing

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ui-testing

I'm trying to create automated UI tests for my iOS app. After generally failing to get this working on my existing app, I created a new one from scratch and tried there. It always seems to fail because it can't import dependencies I've installed with Cocoapods.

I'm currently running XCode Version 10.2.1 (10E1001)

Instructions to replicate:

1. Launch XCode, create new project (Single View App, Swift, unit tests and UI tests). I named my project `UITestProto`
2. Run `pod init` on the project.
3. Add the `HydraAsync` dependency

The Podfile should look like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.2'

target 'UITestProto' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for UITestProto

  target 'UITestProtoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'UITestProtoUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'HydraAsync'
  end
end
```

4. Go to the Build Settings of the `UITestProtoUITests` target in XCode and set "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" to `$(inherited)`:

[image: Embedded swift std libs]

5. Run `pod install`
6. Open the project using `UITestProto.xcworkspace`
7. Open the `UITestProtoUITests.swift` file and try to import the OHHTTPStubs module.

```
import XCTest

import Hydra

class UITestProtoUITests: XCTestCase {
...
```

At this point you should see the error:

> No such module 'Hydra'

I've tried:

1. adding `@testable import UITestProto` because I've had to do that for my unit tests
2. Making sure "Enable Testability" in "Build Settings" is set to "Yes"

And I've cleaned the build folder and closed/open XCode after each of those steps, but still no luck on the Hydra import.

*Note: I'm not actually using Hydra for testing, it's just a library that I've successfully used in projects in the past*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to a [CocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5250). The workaround suggested [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5250#issuecomment-424301165) does the trick for me. You may need to rebuild the project though.

For future reference, I've cc-ed the post:

```rb
# Moving the UITests target outside of the main target 
# in the Podfile seems to have helped. So now instead of this:

target 'Target' do
  use_frameworks!
  ...

  target 'TargetTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    ...
  end

  target 'TargetUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    ...
  end

end

## we have this:

target 'Target' do
  use_frameworks!
  ...

  target 'TargetTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    ...
  end
end

target 'TargetUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    ... # all the pods we normally use
 end
```

Credits to [PWrzesinski](https://github.com/PWrzesinski)

Comment: After cleaning, the error still didn't go away. I ran the tests despite the error, and it built successfully and ran the UI tests just fine. No more module import error.

Comment: Had pretty much the same issue today. I think Xcode is just slow making the connections as it also sometimes does with new classes etc. Running and building the appropriate targets (in my case the unit test target) did the trick as well. See answer below. : )

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
platform :ios, '12.2'

target 'UITestProto' do

  #some pods for your main target

  target 'UITestProtoTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    #pods for your unit tests
  end

  target 'UITestProtoUITests' do
    pod 'HydraAsync'
  end
end
```

And run `pod deintegrate` and `pod update && pod install` after this.

Comment: You want me to remove `use_frameworks!` and `inherit! :search_paths` for the UI test target?

Comment: I tried this by just removing `inherit! :search_paths` but got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

**Same behaviour still with XCode 12.3 in 2021. Easy fix for me by just running the tests once.**

I had the same issue with another pod added to the unit tests or UI tests. The podfile had the pod in the right target section. So it should recognize it.

**The error went away as soon as I ran the tests (`Cmd+U`)**
Only building or running it is not enough since it won't try to build anything of the test targets.

The same problem sometimes happens when adding a new module, class etc. but also fixes itself after building the propper target.